# LoadLibrary - correct CleanUp in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, loadlibrary, resource-cleanup

I have this little code in C++ Visual Studio 2012 for calling static function from dll file build with cygwin, and this code below totally works. the problem is, sometimes it crashes on the function call, or outputs result values as usually to the console, but debugger in Visual Studio is not moving forward. Odd behaviour. I guess maybe I'm not cleaning up correctly after I exit the application? First time I load VS, it works, but after some debug and crashes, this starts happening.

```
PFN_HELLO fnHello;
HMODULE hLib, h = LoadLibrary(TEXT("cygwin1.dll")); 
PFN_CYGWIN_DLL_INIT init = (PFN_CYGWIN_DLL_INIT) GetProcAddress(h,"cygwin_dll_init");
init();

hLib = LoadLibrary (TEXT("cyghello.dll"));

if (NULL == hLib)
{
DWORD _err = GetLastError();
//return 1;
}

//typedef LRESULT (WINAPI *PFN)(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
// PFN MySendMessageW;

//MySendMessageW = (PFN) GetProcAddress(hLib,"runMainRoutine");

fnHello = (PFN_HELLO) GetProcAddress (hLib, "runMainRoutine@4");


if (NULL == fnHello)
{
DWORD _err = GetLastError();
//return 1;
}


char* _bablabla = fnHello(_input);

FreeLibrary(h);
FreeLibrary(hLib);

return _bablabla;
```

Comment: One things I noticed. Changing __stdcall in external dll to __cdecl dramatically improved situation, but still fails oftenly.

Comment: At what line exactly is the problem happening? Also, what's _bablabla? Should you delete this pointer later? Is it a pointer to some static data inside dll? It looks to me, you're using it wrong anyway, because even if it's dynamically allocated, dll may be using its own heap and thus you'll need to deallocate it from within the dll. If it's not dynamically allocated, using it when dll is unloaded will cause all kinds of problems.

Comment: It happens on this line: char* _bablabla = fnHello(_input);  fnHello is function inside dll, which opens some file, does some calculations, and returns char*.  It is defined as: char* __declspec(dllexport) __cdecl runMainRoutine(char _inputString2[])  So I need to clean something up inside the dll as well?

Comment: I should delete char* _bablabla point later? Hmmm. If I unload dll, doesn't it deallocate this data as well? It is not static. It is defined inside function as char* finalResult;

Comment: It might be deleting the pointer, or it may rely on you to delete it. In any case the problem is that you're returning this pointer to be used after the dll is unloaded.

Comment: I see, thank you. I'll try to work it out now, keeping your comment in mind.

Comment: Also, the problem may as well be the input you're giving to the function. You've not specified here what the _input is. Seeing self-contained example would be really useful. But at least, you could show us the crash stack.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who ever returns char* from DLL static function, you have to allocate char[] not in dll, but in your application (caller).

Comment: Good rule of thumb (in conjunction with a function signature that looks like `std::fgets` in `<cstdio>`), but unless I'm forgetting something important about DLLs, it's not necessarily required. If it's a single-threaded application or there's some sort of locking mechanism or it's guaranteed that the data pointed to will never change, returning a pointer to a static array declared in the function definition (or in some other pseudo-global way) should be safe.